# Iterating through tuple elements for product()

Tags: python, python-itertools, cartesian-product

So I have the list of tuple as below

`mylist = [(9.9, 10.0, 11.0), (19.8, 20.0, 21.0), (21.5, 22.1, 24.3)]`

My problem is that I want to put each element of the list into the `itertools.product()` function to generate a cartesian expression.

For example, using the above list of tuple, I want it to generate as below:

`itertools.product(mylist[0], mylist[1], mylist[2], .... mylist[n])`

In this case, `mylist[0]` would be `(9.9, 10.0, 11.0)`, `mylist[1]` would be `(19.8, 20.0, 21.0)` and so on.

How can I implement as above? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `product(*mylist)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list unpacking.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import product

mylist = [(9.9, 10.0, 11.0), (19.8, 20.0, 21.0), (21.5, 22.1, 24.3)]
product(*mylist)
```